# How to force engine (eg. Stockfish) to play position till checkmate in Lucas Chess?

Tags: engines, endgame, stockfish

I am training endgames using Lucas Chess and playing the position from FEN against Stockfish. But sometimes I would like to have engines play the position with itself. I can achieve this in Lucas Chess easilly with 'Engine Tournament'. But the problem is that there is a FEN position, in 3 moves the evaluation goes to -3 for black and the match ends because engine resigns.

I would like to force engine to play itself till the very end so I can see the plan used to win the ending. I can of course use additional program and make a move suggested by it (eg. Scid with Stockfish too) but I would like it better to have only one program used. Is there any setting for an engine that can force it?

Comment: The GUI forces resignation, and I don't see a way to turn it off...

Comment: Maybe any other GUI? But I would like straight answer, do not have time to install 20 of them ;(

Comment: I'm sure Chessbase doesn't resign for me.

Comment: But simple ChessBase Reader got that functionality? And I do not mean that engine resigns when playing me - I mean when engine plays against engine.

Comment: Not sure. Someone else may be able to answer your question.

Comment: I don't know Lucas Chess, but I would look around for a setting or option like "resign threshold". As Student says it's not the engine that's resigning, it's Lucas resigning "on behalf of" the engine.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but you'll may need to update the source code.

In https://github.com/lukasmonk/lucaschess/blob/843be9f57baa3f631c05181b1012df844f53c84b/Code/QT/PantallaEntMaq.py

```
    # Resign
    lbResign = Controles.LB2P(self, _("Resign/draw by engine"))
    liResign = ((_("Very early"), -100),
                (_("Early"), -300),
                (_("Average"), -500),
                (_("Late"), -800),
                (_("Very late"), -1000),
                (_("Never"), -9999999))
    self.cbResign = Controles.CB(self, liResign, -800)
```

The GUI will resign if the score goes below 800 cp. You can do this:

```
self.cbResign = Controles.CB(self, liResign, -9999999)
```

This will disable auto resign for the software.

Answer (score 0):

Chess engines will play till checkmate :)
Only GUIs can be set to give up face to indefensible positions (+10 for B, or -10 for W).
ARENA, for example, can be set to play till K's death.